# Remove all symbols in String except some

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to remove all symbols in the `String` except `()`, but I don't know how to write correct `Regex pattern` and then use `.removeAll()` method.

### Example

`Some text (some 1 text()), and (some 2 text)` -> `(())()`.

Comment: So you want to write a regex pattern for "every character not in the set { "(", ")" }, right? Have you looked at the `java.util.regex.Pattern` documentation to look at how to construct a set of characters, and how to negate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `search` function you can use following regex :

```
[()]
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r//

if you want to use a replace function you can replace the following regex with empty string :

```
[^()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern: `[^()]*` and remove all the matched symbols.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH9qS7/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use can you replace all method.This result the string which replaces empty string for characters other than ( and ).

```
string.replaceAll("[^()]", "")
```

Example :-

```
String val="Some text (some 1 text()), and (some 2 text)";
System.out.println(val.replaceAll("[^()]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:--

```
   String s = "Some text (some 1 text()), and (some 2 text)";
   String s2 = s.replaceAll("[^()]*", "");
   System.out.println(s2);
```

output :-- (())()

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
String thatString = "ad()";
String newString = "";
for(int i = 0;i<thatString.length();i++){
if(thatString.charAt(i)=='(' || thatString.charAt(i)==')'){
 newString+=thatString.charAt(i);
}
}
```

That should work :)